# Framework incompatibility issue when using DNX

Tags: asp.net, dnx

I created an ASP.NET MVC 6 web application project "OpsTools". The project json file is:

```
    {
      "webroot": "wwwroot",
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta6",
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "jqGridWebApi": "1.1.4",
        "OrionSharedObjects": "4.7.0.1",
        "EnyimMemcached": "2.13.0",
        "CouchbaseNetClient": "1.2.7",
        "xunit": "2.2.0-beta1-build3239",
        "Moq": "4.2.1510.2205"
      },
      "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
      },
      "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
          "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
          }
        }
      },
      "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
      ],
      "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
      ],
      "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "Staging": { }
      }
    }
```

Then I add a new class package library project for unit test in the solution. I tried to reference the first project. I found that the project.json in the second project is:

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "OpsTools": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
}
```

The thing is I got many compiling errors. Basically they are

> The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  OpsTools.Test.DNX Core 5.0  C:\Source\Optools\src\OpsTools.Test\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: Why you use **beta6** now? The current version is RC1 and RC2 will be published soon. Why you use old EF6 (`EntityFramework": "6.1.3"`)?

Comment: @Oleg, I have downloaded RC1. Can I just replace beta6 with RC1? And EF6 is not the issue addressed.

Comment: It's not so simple. Many package names are renamed: EntityFramework (now EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer or EntityFramework.Core), Logging (now like `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`), `hosting.ini` is now `hosting.json` and so on and so on. Do you use Visual Studio 2015 Update 1?

Comment: Yes, I use Visual Studio 2015 update 1

Comment: In the case it's more easy to create new project and extend it to the working solution. Visual Studio 2015 update 1 uses updated templates. You should at least look at the list of dependencies of `project.json` of the new project.

Comment: @Oleg, I tried your method. But many red wave lines in the project.json. Example: `The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers 6.0.0-rc1-final in project OpsTools does not support framework DNXCore, Version=v5.0`

Comment: What is "OpsTools"? Is it some legacy class library or you can create new project for the library too? If the library can't be compiled for `dnxcore50` then you should just remove `"dnxcore50": { }` from your main project. You should take in consideration that `dnxcore50` is reduced, but optimized version of .net. Thus it's recommended to use the destination (probably as your default framework) if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the projects are using different frameworks. They are beta version and unstable. It is hard to coordinate them. I just delete the second project.